The equation $x^3=b$ has a solution in $\mathbb{Q}_p$ if and only if $3|n$ and $x^3=u$ has a solution in $\mathbb{Z}_p^{\times}$.
Let $p$ be prime. Suppose $b=p^nu \in \mathbb{Q}_p^{\times}$, where $u \in \mathbb{Z}_p^{\times}$.
The equation $x^3=b$ has a solution in $\mathbb{Q}_p$ if and only if $3|n$ and $x^3=u$ has a solution in $\mathbb{Z}_p^{\times}$.
Suppose $x^3=b$ has a solution $x_0$ in $\mathbb{Q}_p$:
Define the polynomial $f(x):=x^3-b$. Then $f(x_0)=0$.
I want to use Hensel's Lemma. I need to calculate $\nu_p(f'(x_0))$ for that.
$f'(x)=3x^2$
I am stuck on calculating $\nu_p(3x_0^2)$.
$3\nu_p(x_0)=\nu_p(x_0^3)=\nu_p(b)=\nu_p(p^nu)=n$, thus $\nu_p(x_0)=\frac{n}{3}$.
I can write $\nu_p(3x_0^2)$ as $\nu_p(3)+ 2\nu_p(x_0)=\nu_p(3)+2\frac{n}{3}$.
I do not know anything about $p$, so if $p=3$, then $\nu_p(3)=1$, else $\nu_p(3)=0$.
Now $f(x_0)=0 \equiv 0 \mod p^{2l+1}$. Thus there exists $x_1 \in \mathbb{Z}_p$ such that $f(x_1)=0$ and $x_1 \equiv x_0 \mod p^{l+1}$.
So we got that a necessary condition is that $3|n$ and since $x_1 \equiv x_0 \mod p^{l+1}$ together with $x_0=p^nu$ we get that $x^3=u$ has to have a solution in $\mathbb{Z}_p^{\times}$.
My questions are:
Is this correct? I did mention that I did have to distinguish two cases ($p=3$ and $p \neq 3$) when calculating $\nu_p(3)$. Because of that, I am not sure if my argument will work.
